# Rewrite a Java array based on the values of another array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working in a little Java project but I can't figure out how to overwrite the elements of an array based on the values on another array.

Basically I have two arrays: `repeated[] = {1,4,0,0,0,3,0,0}` and `hand[] = {1,2,2,2,2,6,6,6}` and I use `repeated[]` to count the amount of times a number appears on `hand[]`, and if it is between 3 and 7 it should overwrite the corresponding element in `hand[]` with a zero but I keep getting this output `{1,0,0,2,2,6,0,6}` when it should give me `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int repeated[] = {1,4,0,0,0,3,0,0};
    int hand[] = {1,2,2,2,2,6,6,6};
    for(int z=0;z<repeated.length;z++){
        if(repeated[z]>=3 && repeated[z]<8){
            for(int f:hand){
                if(hand[f]==(z+1)){
                    hand[f]=0;
                } } } }
    for(int e:hand){
        System.out.print(e+",");
    }
    }
```

Comment: repeated[i] contains the number of times that i+1 occurs in hand; is that the intention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the value in `repeated` is offset by one (because Java arrays start at index zero). Next, you need to test if the value is `>= 3` (because `6` only appears `3` times). And, you could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to print your array. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int repeated[] = { 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 };
    int hand[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6 };
    for (int z = 0; z < repeated.length; z++) {
        if (repeated[hand[z] - 1] >= 3) {
            hand[z] = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hand));
}
```

Output is

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```